# Python: Creating a len(string) and string.isalpha conditional

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a conditional statement that doesn't appear to be working in my Python code. I have tried to read and understand why, and discretely stated there doesn't appear to be a flaw in the booleans. But when I try to place them into a conditional statement, I get syntax errors. Maybe someone can take a look and examine why my code is failing in this instance:

```
userinput = raw_input("Please enter a word: ")

if (len(userinput) > 1 and userinput.isalpha() == True):
    print "Thanks for entering a word."
else:
    print "That was not an acceptable word."
```

Specifically I recieve a syntax error that states:

```
if len(userinput) > 1 and userinput.isalpha() == True):
SyntaxError: invalid syntax                           ^
```

Comment: What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: I receive a syntax error with an arrow ^ that states invalid syntax after true, right below the colon.

Comment: The `len(userinput)` is redundant. All you need is `if userinput.isalpha()` You getting the syntax error from the extra `)`

Answer (score 5):

<del>Because the input string retains the `\n` character causing the input to fail:</del>

<del>Consider using `userinput = raw_input("Please enter a word: ").strip()` instead...</del>

---

Also, `isalpha()` already checks if the length is one or more, reducing your code to:

```
if userinput.isalpha():
    # whatever
```

And then your syntax error goes away quite nicely... (the extra `)` after `userinput)`

Answer (score 2):

The traceback you've pasted shows different code from your original snippet. You have an extra close bracket after `len(userinput)`, which is the cause of the error.

Comment: this is the correct answer to the traceback error, however... +1

Answer (score 1):

I made three corrections:

- The first is in the if statement (isalpha() already returns a boolean)
- The second is the strip function in order to remove extra spaces at the end of the input
- The third are brackets around print strings (in order to make it compatible with python3)

The final code is:

```
userinput = raw_input("Please enter a word: ").strip()

if (len(userinput) > 1 and userinput.isalpha()):
    print ("Thanks for entering a word.")
else:
    print ("That was not an acceptable word.")
```

Comment: okay - thanks for the help. I wasn't sure about the isalpha statement returning a boolean, but that certainly clears things up..

Comment: @steven-rumbalski Correct +1

Comment: quick question @furins - what's the deal with strip()? how do you mean it will remove the return key to submit the raw_input string?

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe it not what you mean but if the user adds a space at the end of the word it will return "not a word".

Comment: I mean: if the user adds a space at the beginning/end of the word it will return "not a word", this may be misleading for the user so stripping whitespaces may make the script a little bit friendly.